# How do I avoid my return function from returning "undefined" when no conditions are true

Tags: javascript

I'm using `getFooBar(x, y)` in another function and want to execute `foo()` or `bar()` depending on the the condition. If none of them are `true`: Do nothing.

But JS doesn't like that. It will always return something and in this case it's `undefined`.

Is it possible to prevent this?

```
getFooBar(x, y) {

    if (x > y) {
        return foo();
    }
    if (y > x) {
         return bar();
    }
}


foo() {
     // do stuff.
}

bar() {
     // do some other stuff.
}
```

Comment: If nothing is explicitly returned it will return undefined.

Comment: Why do you not want it to return undefined?

Comment: Given we all answered together with valuable answers i upvoted u guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `undefined`, you need to make sure that your function returns something no matter how it gets invoked.

You'll need to test for the existence of the arguments. You can do this by checking the built-in `arguments` object's `length` property.

You should also verify that the arguments are of the correct type (I'm assuming you're thinking numbers).

**By the way, your logic doesn't specify what should happen when `x === y`, so unless you check for that condition, the function won't return anything and then when you try to use the return value, you will get `undefined`.**

```js
function getFooBar(x, y) {
    // Make sure both arguments were passed
    if(arguments.length === 2 && typeof x === "number" && typeof y === "number"){    
      if (x > y) {
        return foo();
      }
    
      if (y > x) {
         return bar();
      }
    } else {
      // One or both arguments are missing.
      // You can do whatever you like here.
      // In this example, it will return a failure message,
      // but, you could simply use return with no value.
      return "invalid function call";
    }
}


function foo() {
     // do stuff.
     return "foo";
}

function bar() {
     // do some other stuff.
     return "bar";
}

console.log(getFooBar());
console.log(getFooBar("Tuesday", "Purple"));
console.log(getFooBar(5,5));  // No condition tests for equal arguments, so no value is returned

// This time we'll check to see if there is a value to work with before assuming it's there:
var result = getFooBar(5,5);
if(result){
  console.log(result);
} else {
  console.log("getFooBar(5,5) doesn't return a value.");
}

console.log(getFooBar(5,10));
console.log(getFooBar(10,5));
```

Comment: In this case it returns a string. So, it's not possible to just return nothing?

Comment: @Hevar It is possible for a function to not return a value, but the issue of getting `undefined` actually comes from outside the function when you attempt to use the return value somewhere else. If the function never returned a value and then you attempt to use the return value, you are going to get `undefined`. In these cases, you need to check the return value before using it.

Comment: @Hevar See my updated answer (specifically when `x === y`) to see how no value is returned and how that should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add an empty `return` statement or return a falsy value like `null`, `0`, `undefined` or anything you wish. Also, even if it returns undefined, you can still catch the returned undefined value and do something with it, just like non returning functions. So you either choose to accept and work with an `undefined` return value or write a return value of your own, of whatever type.

```
getFooBar(x, y) {

    if (x > y) {
        return foo();
    }
    if (y > x) {
         return bar();
    }

    return "foobar";
}


foo() {
     // do stuff.
}

bar() {
     // do some other stuff.
}
```

Comment: Even in this case it will return undefined. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/apLnvu3c/

Comment: that's exactly the point, you either accept undefined as a return value or you state a return value yourself :)

Comment: In this case it returns a string. So, it's not possible to just return nothing?

Comment: Nop, you have to deal with a return value somehow, or you can avoid dealing with it, but it'll still be there. Even void functions return void in C++

Comment: @mnemosdev Of course you can return nothing. Just omit the `return` keyword. A function certainly does not have to have a return value. The issue isn't that, it's when some other code attempts to get the return value that `undefined` is entering the picture.

Comment: @scottmarcus the user wants to return NOTHING, which is impossible. You can avoid adding the return statement and it will still return something, undefined.

Comment: @mnemosdev That's not correct. You are confusing what the function *returns* vs. what the function *evaluates to*. A function can, in fact, not return anything just by omitting the `return` keyword. In this case, the function will *evaluate* to `undefined` if/when some code attempts to get its value. `undefined` simply means "there is no value", but the function doesn't return that. The code that attempts to *evaluate* the function is generating that value.

Comment: @scottmarcus that's some valuable information, do you mind editing your post or my post for a future reader?